# Java IOException error / illegal start of expression

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I try to follow some tutorials. The guy I watched wrote this code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         throws java.io.IOException {
          char input;

          System.out.println("Enter a single character from keyboard,then press ENTER :");

          input = (char) System.in.read();

          System.out.println("The character you type was: " + input);

       }
    }
}
```

It seems very simple and it's working fine for him,but I get some errors like :

1. expected ';' after java.io.IOException
2. java illegal start of expression

I mention i use IntelliJ,any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `throws java.io.IOException {` should not be inside main method, but in declaration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra open brace after `main(String[] args)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
      char input;

      System.out.println("Enter a single character from keyboard,then press ENTER :");

      input = (char) System.in.read();

      System.out.println("The character you type was: " + input);

   }
```

Comment: Note the remaining extra brace at the end of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `throws` declaration should not be nested within the method. Instead change your code to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
  char input;

  System.out.println("Enter a single character from keyboard,then press ENTER :");

  input = (char) System.in.read();

  System.out.println("The character you type was: " + input);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic structure of any class in java is like below:

package pkg.name;

import java.lang.*;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

}
}

so you need to update the code like below:

```
   public class Main{
      public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
      char input;
      System.out.println("Enter a single character from keyboard,then press ENTER :");
      input = (char) System.in.read();
      System.out.println("The character you type was: " + input);
  }
 }
```